# Does anybody know of an extension that allows near real time viewing of where people are viewing your site?

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions

I know this question may seem vague, however I'm currently unaware of any extensions for Magento 2.1+ that allows the administrator of a website to see what/if there are any currently connected users to your site.

I'm asking because, I periodically need to do upgrades and re-compilation/etc, and I obviously try and wait until there is little/no traffic on the site for a few minutes.  However, I have noticed that the customers > whos online is extremely limited on what you can see in M2.

Any suggestions/links to extensions that offer this type of visibility, is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using Google Analytics for this functionality. Google Analytics has a [real-time](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en) view where you can see all current users and the pages they are viewing.

1. [Register for an Analytics account](https://www.google.com.au/analytics/)
2. [Configure your Magento instance](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/google-universal-analytics.html) to use your new account